# ios firebase user equals nil

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was trying to make a simple authentication screen on ios using firebase. I did it by watching a tutorial on youtube. I was following everything, but when I push the button to sign in my user var's value turns out to be equal to nil. Because of that it can't segue to the next view. Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

```
    @IBAction func signInButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // TODO: Do some form validation on email and password

    if let email = emailTextField.text, let pass = passwordTextField.text {

        // Check if it's sign in or register
        if isSignIn {
            // Sign in the user with Firebase
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: pass, completion: { (user, error) in
                // Check that user isn't' nil
                if let u = user {
                    // user is found, go to homescreen
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToHome", sender: self)
                }
                else {
                    // Error: check error and show message
                }
            })

        } else {
            // Register the user with Firebase
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: pass, completion: { (user, error) in

                // Check that user isn't nil
                if let u = user {
                    // User is found, go to homescreen
                    print("\(email) \(pass)")
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToHome", sender: self)
                } else {
                    // Error: check error and show message
                    print(error)
                }
            })
        }
    }

}
```

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the value of isSignIn ? The wrong value can lead to problem like trying to sign in for new user or trying  to register with same email and password which already exist. Please check whether value of isSignIn is correct.

Comment: it seems like user is equal nil right at the beginning of the closure

Comment: @Sunilluitel isSignIn var after I press the button is either true or false, depending on the state of segmented control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had tried with ur question it is working fine, check with this answer once again @bag

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!


@IBOutlet weak var signInButton: UIButton!



var isSignIn:Bool = true
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func segmentcontroltapped(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
 isSignIn = !isSignIn
    if isSignIn {
        signInButton.setTitle("signin", for: .normal)
    }else{
   signInButton.setTitle("Register", for: .normal)
    }
}

@IBAction func sigInButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {


    if let email = emailTextField.text, let pass = passwordTextField.text {

        // Check if it's sign in or register
        if isSignIn {
            // Sign in the user with Firebase
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: pass, completion: { (user, error) in
                // Check that user isn't' nil
                if let u = user {
       print("\(email) \(pass)")
                }
                else {
                print(error)
                }
            })

        } else {
            // Register the user with Firebase
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: pass, completion: { (user, error) in

                // Check that user isn't nil
                if let u = user {
                    // User is found, go to homescreen
                    print("\(email) \(pass)")
                 //   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToHome", sender: self)
                } else {
                    // Error: check error and show message
                    print(error)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: wohoo, it finally worked! do you know what was the reason? Thank you so much, man!